# Sinon - Spy on function defined within a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai, sinon

I have a module that exports some express middleware that looks like this:

```
// my_middleware.js

module.exports = (someMiddleware) => {
  function loadExternalData (val) { ... }

  moreMiddleware.use(async function (req, res, next) {
    const externalData = loadExternalData(req.headers['some-info'])

    someMiddleware(externalData, req, res, next)    
  })

  return myMiddleware
}
```

I'm trying to test the return value of `loadExternalData` and I'm not sure how to do it.  I've tried this

```
it ('returns the expected response', function() {
  const myMiddleware = require('my_middleware.js')
  const someMiddleware = require('some_middleware.js')
  const loadExternalData = sinon.spy(myMiddleware, 'loadExternalData')

  myMiddleware(someMiddleware)

  loadExternalData.should.have.returned('some data')
})
```

Which gives me the error `TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property loadRegionInfos as function`

What is the correct way to test this?

Comment: You are missing an end-quote after 'returns the expected response

Comment: Sorry, typo. Fixed.

Comment: Where does `moreMiddleware` come from?